# How to check an input type="file" has a file or not using jquery?

Tags: jquery, validation, input-type-file

I have a file upload control `<input id="File1" type="file" />` in my page... How to check an input type="file"  has a file or not using jquery on click of a button `upload`?

Comment: Uhm, can you not just get the input element and then politely ask it for its "type" attribute?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
if (jQuery('#File1').val()) { /* There are files */ }
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use "required" instead of JQuery. By just one attribute it'll check input=file has file or not.
Example:

```
<input type="file" required/>
```

Comment: not working for me, form still got sent with an empty field.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('#upload').bind('click', function(e){
   if( $('#File1').val() != ""){
       // file selected
   }
   else{
       // no file selected
   }
});
```